# Installing dependencies in configure script

Tags: linux, llvm, autotools

I'm writing a program that requires LLVM, and thinking of using autotools to ship it on Linux, so from the user's viewpoint the process would look like the well-known `./configure && make && sudo make install`.

With autotools, one normally relies on the system package manager to install dependencies. The problem is that, for whatever reason, this doesn't work with LLVM; on Ubuntu 14.04, `apt-get` thinks the latest version is 3.4, whereas a more recent version would actually be needed. Thus, I need to supply a script to download and build LLVM first (a local copy thereof, not interfering with any older version that might be on the system), a process which takes a few hours.

The most obvious place to put this process is at the start of `configure`. Is this considered normal and reasonable? Or is there a convention that `configure` should only contain the things autotools normally puts in it, and installing dependencies should be another script that the user runs first and separately? In the latter case, is there a convention regarding what that separate script should be called?

Comment: It's normal for Ubuntu 14.04 to contain an old LLVM because 14.04 was 2 years ago. System package managers never install newest software versions, they install versions contained in the distribution.

Comment: @wRAR Okay so it's not just a glitch on my end, it's normal and to be expected that I have to make my own arrangements for version-sensitive dependencies, fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't install anything during configure. The scripts name is "configure" not "install-dependencies".

Write a configure check, and if llvm is missing, Give the user an explanation how to install it. If necessary provide a separate script to download llvm.

It is good practice to run configure (and make) as normal unprivileged user and not as root. So you may not even have permissions to install anything. You would have to check if "sudo" is installed, etc. 
It may also happen that the system the user is installing has no network connectivity (firewall etc.), so your download will fail.